# How to localize crop screen of react-native-image-crop-picker for Android?

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

For iOS we have 2 props *cropperChooseText* and *cropperCancelText* to localize these buttons inside Crop screen

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
  cropperChooseText: 'any text...', //ios only
  cropperCancelText: 'any text...', //ios only
})
```

and we can add languages to localizate the camera / gallery / cropper text buttons:

- Open your Xcode project
- Go to your project settings by opening the project name on the Navigation (left side)
- Select your project in the project list
- Should be into the Info tab and add in Localizations the language your app was missing throughout the +
- Rebuild and you should now have your app camera and gallery with the classic ios text in the language you added.

But how to localize Crop screen on Android?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve localization for Android I have added next files:

[YOUR_PROJECT_NAME]/android/app/src/main/res/values-**ua**/strings.xml
[YOUR_PROJECT_NAME]/android/app/src/main/res/values-**ru**/strings.xml
[YOUR_PROJECT_NAME]/android/app/src/main/res/values-**[2 symbol country code]**/strings.xml

with the following content (this is for UA language):

```
<resources>
    <string name="ucrop_label_edit_photo">Виберіть область</string>
    <string name="ucrop_crop">Обрізати</string>
    <string name="ucrop_rotate">Повернути</string>
    <string name="ucrop_scale">Масштаб</string>
    <string name="ucrop_label_original">Ориг.</string>
</resources>
```

Then you need to rebuild the app.

My version of "react-native-image-crop-picker" is "^0.35.1"